# Render the Components after the click

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to render the data table after clicking the button submit .

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{MenuBean.getValues}"
                        type="submit" partialSubmit="true" process="statemenu,dist,@this"
                        style='font-family: font-family : Baskerville, "Baskerville Old Face",
        "Hoefler Text", Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal'
                        update=":form:table,:form:filter"></p:commandButton>



 <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{DataTable.dataTable}" var="table"
                lazy="true" rowKey="#{table.sheet_no}" selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{DataTable.selectedSheet}" scrollable="true"
                scrollHeight="150" rendered="#{DataTable.loaded}"
                style="widht:400px ; margin-left:200px;margin-right:25px">
</p:dataTable>

<h:panelGrid id="filter" columns="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="2"
            rendered="#{DataTable.filter}"
            style="position:absolute;bottom:15px;right:150px;border: 1px solid #1f497d;box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #888888;
            height:auto;width:600px;Text-align:center;">
            <p:outputLabel value="Filter your search to get result."></p:outputLabel>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

Here is the backing bean

```
public String getValues() {
    DataTable.isLoaded = true;
    DataTable.Filter = false;
    System.out.println("getting the values");
    System.out.println(DataTable.isLoaded);
    System.out.println(DataTable.Filter);
    System.out.println(state);
    System.out.println(district);
    return "hello";
```

The DataTable.isLoaded = true;  DataTable.Filter = false; are static boolean value which are  accessed . When isLoaded becomes true i want to show the table and hide the filter panel .. how to do this..??

```
<p:dataTable id="disptable" value="#{DataTable.dataTable}"
            var="table" lazy="true" rowKey="#{table.sheet_no}"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{DataTable.selectedSheet}"
            scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150" rendered="#{DataTable.loaded}"
            style="widht:auto ; margin-left:300px;margin-right:30px"
            widgetVar="tabl">

            <p:column headerText="Sheet Number" style="width:25%">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{table.sheet_no}"></h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="State" style="width:25%">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{table.state_cd}"></h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="District" style="width:25%">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{table.district_cd}"></h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Details" style="width:25%">
                <h:commandLink title="Complete Details" value="Complete Details"></h:commandLink>
            </p:column>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="selectButton" icon="images\show.png"
                    update=":form:disp" oncomplete="PF('Dialog').show()"
                    process="@this,table" style="height:25px;"
                    action="#{tabs.addTabs}" ajax="true" />
                <!--    Count of Items Selected :  -->
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components seem to be a bit overloaded with attributes which don't seem necessary, e.g. partialSubmit, process, selection, scrollable etc.
This shouldn't be the actual problem, but limiting possibilities for errors can help getting closer to the solution.

Some points:

- are these three elements within the same form? You are using *:form:table* and *form:filter* in your update, this doesn't make clear what forms you are using.
- is getValues() giving you any output in the console or is it not even called? You also don't need to return a String, a void method would do the job
- try using #{menuBean.getValues}, with a small m
- try updating @form, not specific elements

Comment: 1. I want to update filter and table on the click of the command button.

2.getvalue is being called and showing it on console . 

3. trying

4.i tried but updating the whole @form did not work.

Comment: This didn't really answer the question what forms you are using. How exactly does DataTable look like? Would be nice if you provided the code, since making the DataTable bean static would contradict the whole purpose of a scoped-bean. I would advice you to just initialize the list within your bean, which would be a much better approach. You also don't have any output within the dataTable, take a look at the [dataTable showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf). Doing this I was able to achieve your desired result.