# Re Rendering the components after the click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces components for the UI development .I am not able to understand how to do the re-rendering part through ajax.

1. when i click on submit button the form should hide the `<p:outputLabel/>` and display the `<p:dataTable> .`
2. On pageload it should show only the `outputLabel` and hide the `dataTable` .

Kindly help

Comment: You can use the simple java script to set the style of  a particular component. Such as `style= display:none`

Comment: Is there anyway to do it in primefaces itself

Comment: Can you please share some code ?

Comment: <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{MenuBean.getValues}"      type="submit" partialSubmit="true" process="statemenu,dist,@this"
update=":form:filter , :form:table">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update the corresponding component after setting the new render value from the bean

```
<p:commandButton  value="Submit" actionListener="#{managedBean.function}"
update="idOfTheComponent idOfTheNextComponent">
```

Make sure that the id given is the exact id for the component, JSF generates the id from the parent(`:parentId:childId`) if no `prependId="false"`  is given (*look into the html in case of any doubt*).  You can also use `@form` to update the entire form.

Comment: did you use @form..??

Comment: Check the id from the html page and print the value of the variables used to render, check whether it shows the same value as expected both the id and the variable Name.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473678/render-the-components-after-the-click), which targets the exact same issue. Posting multiple question won't exactly solve your problem.

Nevertheless, this code works perfectly fine for me.

**xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{testBean.go()}" update="@form" />

<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{testBean.list}" var="item" rendered="#{testBean.showTable}">
    <p:outputLabel value="Table" />
</p:dataTable>

<p:outputLabel id="label" value="Label" rendered="#{testBean.showLabel}" />
```

**TestBean**

```
public void go() {
    showTable = !showTable;
    showLabel = !showLabel;
}
```

Updating only the id's of dataTable and outputLabel doesn't work, @form definitely does.